# You guys need to get a room!

Tags: discussion, comments

What constitutes a discussion on a Stack Overflow question in the comments? I've come across several stale questions (20 minutes or so old) that didn't have any answers at all and I find out why, because when I look into it, there's about 3 billion comments on clarifying the topic (I'm being hyperbolic). I also don't see the fancy little "Take it to a chat room" dialog popup either. How should things like that be handled?

Comment: Flag the parent post for cleanup if the comments went out of control, that's about the only thing you can do, we can't force people to post answers.

Comment: +1 for the title, and a not bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of showing the message you are referring, and which suggests the users to discuss about that in a chat room, comments are considered a discussion if only two users are involved, and the comments are X. (I don't recall the number of comments that trigger that message to appear.) If 15 different users comment asking to the author of the post what the meaning of a sentence is, or suggesting something that should be changed in the post, then the message doesn't appear.

I don't think there is the need of using a chat room to suggest to the user what should be clarified in the question, or ask what the OP tried.

Comment: Yeah, that message requires a back-and-forth exchange between (at least) two users. "Let's take this to chat" is also only shown to the discussion participants. It becomes a comment on the post only if one of the participants actually opts to take it to chat and the chatroom is created, etc.

Comment: @Anna is correct but note that once created the room is public and anyone getting there (with enough reputation) can see the whole discussion.